# How to round up a number to nearest 10?

Tags: php, rounding

How can we round off a number to the nearest 10 in php?

Say I have `23`, what code would I use to round it off to `30`?

Comment: Er, that's not the *nearest* 10?

Comment: ok, round up to 1 significant figure then! haha

Comment: To be fair, in the title, it says "round *up* a number to nearest 10", even though the text says "round off" ... I'm pretty sure he's asking to always round *up* to the *next* 10.

Comment: round up to power of 10, http://stackoverflow.com/q/43932648/6521116

Answer (score 252, accepted):

`floor()` will go down.

`ceil()` will go up.

`round()` will go to nearest by default.

Divide by 10, do the ceil, then multiply by 10 to reduce the significant digits.

```
$number = ceil($input / 10) * 10;
```

Edit:  I've been doing it this way for so long.. but TallGreenTree's answer is cleaner.

Comment: TallGreenTree's answer does not always round it UP.  This answer is the most correct with the use of ceil()

Comment: TallGreenTree's answer does support rounding up/down using the third parameter (mode) of round().  round($input,-1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP)

Comment: @DarenSchwenke, that third param doesn't quite work as you assume, that only controls the case of exactly halfway between the intervals. `(15,-1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP); // 20`, `(14,-1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP); // 10`

Answer (score 179):

```
round($number, -1);
```

This will round $number to the nearest 10. You can also pass a third variable if necessary to change the rounding mode.

More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: Can you blame them for assuming the questioner meant "round to the nearest 10" when the question said "round to the nearest 10" twice?

Comment: This answer was posted before the questioner clarified himself. I just figured he wasn't rounding correctly in the question.

Comment: TallGreenTree is correct. You can set the rounding mode with the 3rd argument: "mode

    One of PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN, or PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD.
"

Comment: This doesn't give the right outcome. `23` will be `20` and not `30` because it will always rond to the nearest 10. The rounding mode will not help, since this only round half, after the `x.`.

Comment: +1 for not using the classic `round( $x / $y ) * $y` solution. Avoiding the division and multiplication can save precious clock cycles

Comment: Sad that ceil() and floor() don't have the precision parameter yet.

Answer (score 22):

I was actually searching for a function that could round to the nearest variable, and this page kept coming up in my searches. So when I finally ended up writing the function myself, I thought I would post it here for others to find.

**The function will round to the nearest variable:**

```
function roundToTheNearestAnything($value, $roundTo)
{
    $mod = $value%$roundTo;
    return $value+($mod<($roundTo/2)?-$mod:$roundTo-$mod);
}
```

This code:

```
echo roundToTheNearestAnything(1234, 10).'<br>';
echo roundToTheNearestAnything(1234, 5).'<br>';
echo roundToTheNearestAnything(1234, 15).'<br>';
echo roundToTheNearestAnything(1234, 167).'<br>';
```

Will output:

```
1230
1235
1230
1169
```

Comment: Kenny, you are the best. I only wish I had a graphic representation of how it rounds exactly so I'm sure it gives the expected results in 100% of cases. I guess I'll have to do some testing.

Comment: Is there any way to modify this code to add a third parameter with round mode HALF_UP / HALF_DOWN?

Comment: Does not work for the number: 2560.9999999999995

Answer (score 12):

There are many anwers in this question, probably all will give you the answer you are looking for. But as @TallGreenTree mentions, there is a function for this.

But the problem of the answer of @TallGreenTree is that it doesn't round up, it rounds to the nearest 10. To solve this, add `+5` to your number in order to round up. If you want to round down, do `-5`.

So in code:

```
round($num + 5, -1);
```

You can't use the `round mode` for rounding up, because that only rounds up fractions and not whole numbers.

If you want to round up to the nearest `100`, you shoud use `+50`.

Comment: This doesn't work for non-decimal numbers. 10 becomes 20

Answer (score 7):

div by 10 then use ceil then mult by 10

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php

Answer (score 3):

We can "cheat" via round with

```
$rounded = round($roundee / 10) * 10;
```

We can also avoid going through floating point division with

```
function roundToTen($roundee)
{
  $r = $roundee % 10;
  return ($r <= 5) : $roundee - $r : $roundee + (10 - $r);
}
```

Edit: I didn't know (and it's not well documented on the site) that `round` now supports "negative" precision, so you can more easily use

```
$round = round($roundee, -1);
```

Edit again: If you always want to round up, you can try

```
function roundUpToTen($roundee)
{
  $r = $roundee % 10;
  if ($r == 0)
    return $roundee;
  return $roundee + 10 - $r;    
}
```

Comment: hi, this works perfectly - for that question, how can i round UP? so 23 to 30?

Answer (score 3):

to nearest 10 , should be as below

```
$number = ceil($input * 0.1)/0.1 ;
```

Comment: Great answer. Much simpler than the other methods. If you want to round down to the nearest 10, just change `ceil` to `floor`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

`round(23, -1);`

Answer (score 2):

```
$value = 23;
$rounded_value = $value - ($value % 10 - 10);
//$rounded_value is now 30
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to round up to the next number in the largest digits place (is there a name for that?), so I made the following function (in php):

```
//Get the max value to use in a graph scale axis, 
//given the max value in the graph
function getMaxScale($maxVal) {
    $maxInt = ceil($maxVal);
    $numDigits = strlen((string)$maxInt)-1; //this makes 2150->3000 instead of 10000
    $dividend = pow(10,$numDigits);
    $maxScale= ceil($maxInt/ $dividend) * $dividend;
    return $maxScale;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , this is what i have been looking for , If number is 54000 it rounds upto 60000 if 5600 it rounds upto 6000.

Comment: You're welcome @RoshJ, I'm glad it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ceil($roundee / 10) * 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

My first impulse was to google for "php math" and I discovered that there's a core math library function called "round()" that likely is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

For people who want to do it with raw SQL, without using php, java, python etc. 
`SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
UPDATE db.table SET value=ceil(value/10)*10 where value not like '%0';`

Answer (score 0):

```
Hey i modify Kenny answer and custom it not always round function now it can be ceil and floor function

function roundToTheNearestAnything($value, $roundTo,$type='round')
    {
        $mod = $value%$roundTo;
        if($type=='round'){
            return $value+($mod<($roundTo/2)?-$mod:$roundTo-$mod);
        }elseif($type=='floor'){
            return $value+($mod<($roundTo/2)?-$mod:-$mod);
        }elseif($type=='ceil'){
            return $value+($mod<($roundTo/2)?$roundTo-$mod:$roundTo-$mod);
        }

    }

echo roundToTheNearestAnything(1872,25,'floor'); // 1850<br>
echo roundToTheNearestAnything(1872,25,'ceil'); // 1875<br>
echo roundToTheNearestAnything(1872,25,'round'); // 1875
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily accomplished using PHP '**fmod**' function. The code below is specific to 10 but you can change it to any number.

```
$num=97;
$r=fmod($num,10);
$r=10-$r;
$r=$num+$r;
return $r;
```

OUTPUT: 100

Answer (score -2):

Try this......pass in the number to be rounded off and it will round off to the nearest tenth.hope it helps....

round($num, 1);