# How to round up integer in PHP?

Tags: php, integer, rounding

I want to round up any an integer to the next tens place number.

Some examples to illustrate my point:

-- I have the number 1, I would like this rounded up to 10

-- I have the number 35, I would like this rounded up to 40

-- I have the number 72, I would like this rounded up to 80

-- etc etc

```
// $category_count's value is 38
for($i = 1; $i <= $category_count; $i++) 
{ 
       if($i % 10 == 0)
       {
          echo "<a href=\"?page=$i\">$i;</a>"; 
       }
    }
```

The above code outputs 3 links, I need the fourth too.

Comment: see here for answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619265/round-to-nearest-10

Comment: "Tenth place" would mean you want to round to .1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `for` is ineffective. If you need to modulus 10 your counter, use this code instead :

```
for($i = 1, $c = ceil($category_count/10); $i <= $c; $i++) 
{ 
    $j = $i * 10;
    echo "<a href=\"?page=$j\">$j;</a>"; 
}
```

Comment: imo better to store the ceil() result first otherwise it is evaluated every loop cycle

Comment: @YanickRochon Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Edited my answer to point to this question instead. Basically same thing with many good answers.

[How to round up a number to nearest 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619265/round-to-nearest-10)

Comment: This doesn't round up all the time though? echo round(3.4);         // 3

Comment: @KeithDonegan from the docs `mode: One of PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN, or PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD` and there are examples.  Click the link @mrtsherman so kindly posted for you. :)

Comment: @sequoiamcdowell - I hate it when people can't even take fifteen seconds to read the docs. A google search could have solved this in a minute.

Comment: The sad thing is he (and perhaps others) is probably going to use the code from the accepted answer to a) unintentionally obfuscate the code and b) recreate something that php does natively. :(

Answer (score 2):

mrtsherman is almost right but OP's question needed it to round UP (1 => 10)

```
// $category_count's value is 38
$loop_limit = ceil($category_count/10);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $loop_limit; $i++) {
  $page = $i * 10;
  echo "<a href=\"?page={$page}\">{$page}</a>";
}
```

Comment: If you read the docs you will see that the round function is perfectly capable of this.

Comment: looked at it and it still won't round 0.1 -> 1 (which is what we need)

Answer (score 1):

```
round(($num/10))*10; // Make sure num is an integer or use (int) to convert string to integer.
```

This works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to add 9, then truncate it at the tens place (integer divide by ten, then multiply by ten).

Alternatively, you can add 5 then use the `round` function with a negative precision:

```
echo round ($i + 5, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
(int(i/10) + 1) x 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
ceil($category_count/10)*10
```