# Get total size in MB from database

Tags: php, mysql, megabyte

I'm trying to get and show total size of row from database,

PHP:

```
$swall = $db->super_query("SELECT sum(size) as sum FROM dle_photo_post");
$tpl->set("{swall}", $swall['sum']);
```

With above code, my result is like his: 82447456

Example 2:
With this Code:

```
$swall = $db->super_query("SELECT sum(size)/1024 as sum FROM dle_photo_post");
$tpl->set("{swall}", $swall['sum']);
```

I got this: 80515.0938

but i need to show total in MB, like this: **80 MB**

how i can show total size result in megabyte?

Comment: it's just formatting, devide it by 1000 and then round it

Comment: Well,I'm not php dev but see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619265/round-to-nearest-10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$swall = $db->super_query("SELECT sum(size)/1024/1024 as sum FROM dle_photo_post");
$tpl->set("{swall}", number_format($swall['sum'], 0));
```

Then you can use number_format (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to format the size.

Comment: with your help i got a total result like this: 78.62802124, but my problem is i'm not pro with php and i checked your link, but i cant understand how i can convert this numbers to MB! i really appreciate if u helping me more. thanks

Comment: I added the number_format line (untested however), does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Value is returned in Bytes. You have to divide the value two times with 1024 (B > KB > MB).

`(sum(size)/1024)/1024 or $tpl->set("{swall}", ($swall['sum'])/1024);`