# How to format a float to n decimal places

Tags: php

Example:

> 22.453667 => 22.45
>
> 34.65355 => 34.65

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619265/how-to-round-off-a-number-to-nearest-10

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Answer (score 2):

You should use PHP's [`round`](https://www.php.net/round) function:

```
<?php
echo round(3.4);         // 3
echo round(3.5);         // 4
echo round(3.6);         // 4
echo round(3.6, 0);      // 4
echo round(1.95583, 2);  // 1.96
echo round(1241757, -3); // 1242000
echo round(5.045, 2);    // 5.05
echo round(5.055, 2);    // 5.06
?>
```

Comment: Any options : echo round(3,4453);         // 3,44 
echo round(3,536);         // 3,53
echo round(3,6783);         // 3,37

Answer (score 1):

use [number_format](https://www.php.net/number_format):

```
$num = "22.469667";

// Without round
echo number_format( floor($num*100) / 100, 2, '.', '' );
// output: 22.46

echo "\n"; 

// With round
echo number_format($num, 2, '.', '' );
// output: 22.47
```

http://codepad.org/BjGiEeVa

Answer (score 1):

[use round function](https://www.php.net/round..)

`echo round(2.98684, 2);  The output is  2.99`

Answer (score 0):

number_format() is a lot easier than jogesh_pi made it out to be.

Just do:

```
$num = "22.453667";
echo number_format($num, 2);
```

which returns: 22.45

It just needs the number as the first parameter and then the number of decimal points you want it to round to.

$num = "22.457667"; would return 22.46
$num = "22"; would return 22.00

http://codepad.org/9zollLf5