# Round number down the to the nearest hundredth using php

Tags: php

I'm probably not looking hard enough but the common question about php rounding is rounding up, not down.

For example I am trying round this..

```
<?php $roundDown = 768; ?>
```

Down to..

```
<?php var_dump($roundDown) /* 700 */ ?>
```

Whats the simplest method to do this, or is it because the number is closer to 800 that it's not technically rounding?

Whats the function that I need to do this if it's not rounding?

A little point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Frankly, I think the easiest way to do this is change the last two digits in the number to 00, that will work every time.

Comment: @RussJ funniest comment, I might have just found my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619265/how-to-round-up-a-number-to-nearest-10

Comment: It works though ;-)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can try ceil() and floor() function.

```
 echo floor(768 / 100) * 100;  // Output:700
 echo ceil(768 / 100) * 100;  // Output:800
```

Comment: Just figured it exact same way using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619265/how-to-round-up-a-number-to-nearest-10 but solid answer.. so simple. Need to work on my math. Thanks dude