# Php "round" function , not working as expected?

Tags: php

I'm trying to round up the value if it has cents, for example:

`69990` to be `70000`, I'm working on none USD currency, I've tried many answers in the community, I couldn't make it work .

My example code :

```
$gg = rtrim(number_format(69990, 1), '.');
echo $gg . "\n <br />";
echo round($gg , 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
echo  "\n <br />";
echo number_format($gg,2);
```

And the output is :

```
69,990.0
 <br />69
 <br />69.00
```

Comment: you need to read the docs carefully

Comment: `round` expects a float value as first parameter, you are giving it a string. So that string value needs to be casted into a float first - but you provided it in a format, that PHP does not “understand”. PHP does not recognize the comma as thousands-separator, this is an _invalid_ character in a number to PHP, so it cuts of before that. Therefor the actual value you are “rounding” _is_ only 69 at that point already.

Comment: @CBroe also when i do ` floatval(number_format(69990,` its give 69

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's [`round()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php):

> Rounds a float

---

You're trying to 'round' on each 1000'st number.

You should use php's [`ceil()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) like so;

```
<?php

    $n = 69990;
    
    // WRONG: Only for decimals
    echo round($n , 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP) . PHP_EOL;
    // 69990
    
    // Nearest 'whole'
    echo ceil($n / 1000) * 1000 . PHP_EOL;
    // 70000
```

[Try online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fd8295ee8e2bb00d495e10e2b75e8c0d1396cee7)

[How to round up a number to nearest 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619265/how-to-round-up-a-number-to-nearest-10)

Comment: exactly what i need , many thanks , it have been very long time for me with php :D